# custom html field in the django admin changelist_view

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I'd like to some little customisation with the django admin -- particularly the `changelist_view`

```
class FeatureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'content_object_change_url',
        'content_object',
        'content_type',
        'active',
        'ordering',
        'is_published',
    )

    list_editable = (
       'active',
       'ordering',
    )

    list_display_links = (
        'content_object_change_url',
    )

admin.site.register(get_model('features', 'feature'), FeatureAdmin)
```

The idea is that the `'content_object_change_url'` could be a link to another object's `change_view`... a convenience for the admin user to quickly navigate directly to the item.

The other case I'd have for this kind of thing is adding links to external sources, or thumbnails of image fields.

I had thought I'd heard of a 'insert html' option -- but maybe I'm getting ahead of myself.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can provide a custom method on the `FeatureAdmin` class which returns HTML for `content_object_change_url`:

```
class FeatureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    [...]

    def content_object_change_url(self, obj):
        return '<a href="%s">Click to change</a>' % obj.get_absolute_url()
    content_object_change_url.allow_tags=True
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Comment: has now changed to `mark_safe` in Django 2.0 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953705/how-do-i-use-allow-tags-in-django-2-0-admin

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention and use format_html (See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html)) as the [mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) util has been deprecated since version 1.10. Moreover, support for the allow_tags attribute on ModelAdmin methods will be removed since version 1.11.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib import admin

class FeatureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'change_url',
        [...]
    )
    def change_url(self, obj):
        return format_html('<a target="_blank" href="{}">Change</a>', obj.get_absolute_url())
    change_url.short_description='URL'
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me two hours to find out why Daniel Roseman's solution doesn't work for me. Even though he is right, there's one exception: when you want to make custom calculated fields (*read only*) in the `Admin`. This wont work. The very easy solution (but hard to find) is to return your string in a special constructor: `SafeText()`. Maybe this is linked with Django 2 or with `readonly_fields` (which behave differently from classical fields)

Here's a working sample that works but doesn't without `SafeText()`:

```
from django.utils.safestring import SafeText

class ModelAdminWithData(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def decrypt_bin_as_json(self, obj):
        if not obj:
            return _("Mode insert, nothing to display")
        if not obj.data:
            return _("No data in the game yet")
        total = '<br/><pre>{}</pre>'.format(
            json.dumps(json.loads(obj.data),
                       indent=4).replace(' ', '&nbsp;'))
        return SafeText(total)  # !! working solution !! <------------------

    decrypt_bin_as_json.short_description = _("Data")
    decrypt_bin_as_json.allow_tags = True

    readonly_fields = ('decrypt_bin_as_json',)

    fieldsets = (
        (_('Data dump'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('decrypt_bin_as_json',)
        }),
    )
```