# How do I use allow_tags in django 2.0 admin?

Tags: python, django

> Support for the allow_tags attribute on ModelAdmin methods is removed.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Just found the answer, use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) function.

In old code, you may use:

```
def image_(self, obj):
    return '<image src="%s" />' % obj.image
image_.allow_tags = True
```

In new code, you should use:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
def image(self, obj):
    return mark_safe('<image src="%s" />' % obj.image)
```

Comment: See Django 1.9 release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.9/#id1

Comment: Docs [recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) `format_html()`: "... So, instead of writing: `mark_safe(...)` ... You should instead use: `format_html(...)` ..."

Answer (score 28):

Additionaly to the other answers you can use the `mark_safe` function as decorator:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@mark_safe
def icon_pw(self, obj):
    return f'<img src="{obj.icon.url}" />' if obj.icon else ''
icon_pw.short_description = 'Icon'
icon_pw.allow_tags = True
```

This is the easy way to upgrade your old Django admin code to 2.0.

Answer (score 8):

If you have your code in `admin.py` you can overwrite adding only `mark_safe` function, like the example below:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def get_image_tag(self):
        if self.picture:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="60" height="75" />' % self.picture.url)
        else:
            return ' '
get_image_tag.short_description = 'Photo'
#get_image_tag.allow_tags = True #redundant
get_image_tag.admin_order_field = 'name'
```

This code was tested in Django 2.0.2 and Python 3.6.4.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: You should probably use [`format_html()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) rather than `mark_safe`, as recommended by other answers.

The way other answers recommend to use `mark_safe` will just mark the *entire* resulting string as safe HTML. IOW, you're telling Django "This is valid and safe HTML, I have ensured any needed escaping has happened". Except that the other answers do not actually do the required escaping.

Consider the following (imperfect) approach from another answer:

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
def image(self, obj):
    return mark_safe('<image src="%s" />' % obj.image)
```

If `obj.image` now contains a `"`, or worse, is user input and contains an XSS attack, this will break the resulting HTML.

To prevent this, all data that is interpolated *into* such HTML snippets should be individually escaped beforehand. Fortunately there is the [`html_format()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) which does both interpolation and the needed escaping. With that, the above example would become:

```py
from django.utils.html import format_html
def image(self, obj):
    return format_html('<image src="{}" />', obj.image)
```

Note that his uses `{}` format strings rather than `%s`, since `format_html()` is based on `str.format()`, which uses that style.